# How to highlight an itemize item in an animation flow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, highlighting

I am trying to highlight the second item in an `itemize` after displaying all `items`:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    %#%
    \begin{frame}{slide_1}{}
    
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Key concerns:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item key number 1,\\[.6ex]
            \item key number 2, and\\[.6ex]
            \item key number 3.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}
```

is there any straight way to attract the audience that we will talk about the second `item` like changing the `itemize` shape, highlight text, draw text box around it, .... Not fancy thing.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127369/highlight-the-desired-item?rq=1

Comment: I need the text box to appear last !

Comment: I found this answer: [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300464/highlight-the-item-in-list-after-uncovering-it?rq=1)